# Handling HTTP request redirect in java

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm writing a network android application that uses http requests to get data. The data is HTML format. I use Apache HttpClient and JSoup.

When I'm out of traffic with my mobile internet provider, I am always redirected to the providers' page saying that I should pay some money. Of course, it is a bad idea to parse this page.

How to detect occured page substitution?

Comment: Do you get a proper 300 status code, or does the provider just return "incorrect" data?

Comment: I get 200 (OK) as a status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you to know with is the final target of your request, if isn't the page that you asked for, is the provider page.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
HttpHost target = (HttpHost) localContext.getAttribute(
 ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);// this is the final page of the request
System.out.println("Final target: " + target);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your provider is lying to you by immediately returning a `200 OK` but not giving you the resource you've requested, your best option is probably to set a custom HTTP response header that your client can check before continuing.